# Changing values in arrays of a different class

Tags: c++

(c++ problem) I have two classes A and B, and the main class(int main). I have an array in class A. In the main class, I want to make a change to the array in class A. When class B reads the array from class A, it should read the changed values. However, changes to the array I make in class A through int main take effect for all things in int main only,  NOT class B. In other words, I am unable to permanently change the values *in class A*. 
I created a dummy program (c++) to showcase my problem. If I input 3 for x (first cin) and 9 for y(second cin), the output is

```
00090

0
```

when it should be

```
00090

9
```

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int array[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };

    int getNum(int index)
    {
        return array[index];
    }

    void changeNum(int index, int change)
    {
        array[index] = change;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A obj1;
    int getNum(int index)
    {
        return obj1.getNum(index);
    }

};

int main()
{
    A obj2;
    B obj3;
    int x,y;

    cout << "Original Array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << obj2.getNum(i);

    cout << endl << endl << "Enter index number:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter new number" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    obj2.changeNum(x, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << obj2.getNum(i);

    cout << endl << obj3.getNum(x) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It seems you lack some understanding what a class is, and what an object is. You create two instances of class A, that is directly the variable `obj2`, and also indirectly `obj3.obj1`.

Comment: @Aziuth Not some, alot. I am learning classes through trial and error rather than just reading a textbook or watching a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want changes to the `array` in `A` to be visible globally, then you can make `array` a `static` variable like this:

```
class A {
  public:
    static int array[5];
  // ...
};

int A::array[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
```

From c++17, you could also define `array` inside the class:

```
class A {
  public:
    inline static int array[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/yp7_Ls).

Also, avoid doing `using namespace std;`. e.g. there is already an `std::array`, so variable names like `array` can cause serious problems.